# Validation Rules, make all fields mandatory if value to other field in Yes?

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to write validation Rule but its giving the error `Error: Syntax error. Found ')'`. Could you please help me with this ?

If AAA__c is Yes, then I need to make all the fields (BBB__c, CCC__c, DDD__c, EEE__c, FFF__c) mandatory

```
AND 
( 
NOT 
( 
AND 
( 
Case__r.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'OOO', 
ISPICKVAL(Case__r.SubStatus__c, 'Draft') 
) 
), 
ISPICKVAL(Case__r.Category__c, 'Payment'), 
ISPICKVAL(Case__r.SubCategory__c, 'Auth'), 
INCLUDES(AAA__c, 'Yes'), 
ISBLANK(BBB__c),
ISBLANK(CCC__c),
ISBLANK(DDD__c),
ISBLANK(EEE__c),
ISBLANK(FFF__c),
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra ")" at the end.

```
AND 
( 
    NOT 
    ( 
        AND 
        ( 
            Case__r.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'OOO', 
            ISPICKVAL(Case__r.SubStatus__c, 'Draft') 
        ) 
    ), 
    ISPICKVAL(Case__r.Category__c, 'Payment'), 
    ISPICKVAL(Case__r.SubCategory__c, 'Auth'), 
    INCLUDES(AAA__c, 'Yes'), 
    ISBLANK(BBB__c),
    ISBLANK(CCC__c),
    ISBLANK(DDD__c),
    ISBLANK(EEE__c),
    ISBLANK(FFF__c),
)
```

Comment: +1, but there's also an extra `,` at the end.

Comment: Its not showing any message at the top, how can I show message at each field level ?

Comment: that's not possible! you can only use one field or at the top of a page!

Comment: @user4798115 If you want to show an error on each field, you need to write many validations rule (one per field).

Comment: @sfdcfox, i think only one erro will be shown at a time, right?

Comment: @MoHamada No, during a save function, all validation rules are evaluated, any errors will be attached to the fields, and all the errors will be highlighted at once. This minimizes the number of times the user needs to try and save a record.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes that's right, i've just tested it, thanks!

Comment: How this answer was selected as correct? It will show error ONLY when ALL fields (BBB to FFF) are blank

Comment: This VR doesn't works well. if FFF__c is blank then this VR doesn't works. I want to fire if any of the field is blank.